# How to know whether server is using RED5 or FMS?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, red5, flash-media-server

I am working on a site where a webcam component, made up of flash is being used to stream video. On hosting, there is a flash server setup(via rtmp protocol) which hosts the streamed video. I need to know whether RED5 or FMS is being used for this process. How can I know please? I am not very knowledgeable in video streaming area, so not sure, whether i am clear with my explanation. Please let me know if i need to explain anything else. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just call and ask? Why would you need to know what type of server they have anyway. It should be seem-less to you.

Answer (score 1):

Both Red5 and FMS contain information in their connection success object which allows you to know which server type you are connected to; For example, here is the information sent by red5:

```
NetConnection.onStatus: 
  mode = 1
  fmsVer = RED5/1,0,0,0
  capabilities = 31
  data = 
      version = 4,0,0,1121
      type = red5

  description = Connection succeeded.
  code = NetConnection.Connect.Success
  level = status
```

The property that you'd be most interested in is "fmsVer".